# luasocket.c:20:17: error: lua.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, lua, luasocket

I'm installing luasocket module for Lua, but I got the following error message:

```
[root@localhost local]# wget http://files.luaforge.net/releases/luasocket/luasocket/luasocket-2.0.2/luasocket-2.0.2.tar.gz
[root@localhost local]# tar zxvf luasocket-2.0.2.tar.gz
[root@localhost local]# cd luasocket-2.0.2
[root@localhost luasocket-2.0.2]# make && make install
cd src; make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/luasocket-2.0.2/src'
gcc  -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic   -c -o luasocket.o luasocket.c
luasocket.c:20:17: error: lua.h: No such file or directory
luasocket.c:21:21: error: lauxlib.h: No such file or directory
luasocket.c:24:24: error: compat-5.1.h: No such file or directory
In file included from luasocket.c:30:
luasocket.h:30: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from luasocket.c:31:
auxiliar.h:37: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
auxiliar.h:38: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
auxiliar.h:39: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
auxiliar.h:40: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
auxiliar.h:41: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
auxiliar.h:42: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
auxiliar.h:43: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
auxiliar.h:44: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
auxiliar.h:45: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
auxiliar.h:46: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from luasocket.c:32:
except.h:33: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from luasocket.c:33:
timeout.h:19: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
timeout.h:26: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from luasocket.c:34:
buffer.h:39: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
buffer.h:41: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
buffer.h:42: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
buffer.h:43: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
buffer.h:44: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from luasocket.c:35:
inet.h:27: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
inet.h:35: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
inet.h:36: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from luasocket.c:36:
tcp.h:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from luasocket.c:37:
udp.h:31: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from luasocket.c:38:
select.h:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
luasocket.c:43: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
luasocket.c:44: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
luasocket.c:45: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
luasocket.c:50: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘mod’
luasocket.c:60: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function
luasocket.c:62: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘func’
luasocket.c:66: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function
luasocket.c:71: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
luasocket.c:80: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
luasocket.c:89: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
luasocket.c:113: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
make[1]: *** [luasocket.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/luasocket-2.0.2/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anybody help me? thanks in advance :)

Comment: `lua.h` is the main header file for the Lua C source code. Either you don't have the lua source installed, or you haven't told the compiler where to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to set `LUAINC`.

Since you didn't specify which OS you are using, I can't give you a
definitive answer what to set it to. On Debian, if you want to build
for Lua5.1, set it to `-I/usr/include/lua5.1/`

You can set the variable by editing `config` (which is included from
`makefile`) or by specifying it on the command line:

```
$ make LUAINC=-I/usr/include/lua5.1/
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution did not work for me using Alpine 3.4.  In order to make it work in this environment I had to download the package and hack the following.

```
luasec-luasec-0.6/src/luasocket/usocket.h

 /* TODO: ifdef the ALPINE #include <sys/poll.h> */
 #include <poll.h>
```

Then changes to Makefile

```
# Inform the location to install the modules
LUAPATH  ?= /usr/local/share/lua/5.1
LUACPATH ?= /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1


# Edit the lines below to inform new path, if necessary.
# Path below points to internal LuaSocket's help files.
LUAINCDIR = -I/usr/local/api-gateway/luajit/include/luajit-2.1
INC_PATH ?= -I/usr/include
LIB_PATH ?= -L/usr/lib
INCDIR    = -I. $(LUAINCDIR) $(INC_PATH)       <------ include new path
LIBDIR    = -L./luasocket $(LIB_PATH)
```

Hope this helps if anyone else is stuck with this particular problem.